# Unable to send value from JavaScript to PHP through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to send value from Ajax to PHP but it's not working.

JS

```
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: {id:"1"},
            success: function() {

              $('#display_info').load('update.php');


            }
          });
```

PHP update.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

var_dump($id);
```

And I'm getting following error

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\register\update.php on line 12
NULL

Comment: Well `$_POST` will be empty - and therefore will have no `id` key - when you request the page with a method other than `POST`. And when you request it in the `.load` method in your `success` callback, that's a regular GET request...

Comment: check isset($_POST['id]) in php side

Comment: comment out the lines from your success function and then check whether you are still getting same error or not.

Comment: @RobinZigmond is right. You might try to append HTML to `#display_info` thanks to the first argument of the `success` callback instead.

Comment: you can certainly check for whether `$_POST` exists on the PHP side, as also suggested in the answer below, but I would argue the real root cause is having a success callback which just calls the same URL afresh. I've never seen this, and it feels like a huge antipattern. Why not just have the POST request actually return some data and add this to the page in your success callback? [EDIT: so as @Barmar has now answered, it appeared just after I wrote this :) ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending two AJAX requests.

First, you're sending a request with the `id: 1` parameter using `$.ajax`. But you don't do anything with the response.

Then you perform a second request with `.load()`. This one has no parameters, so you get the warning, and you load this response into the DIV.

You just need one request:

```
$('#display_info').load('update.php', {id: 1});
```

or:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'update.php',
  data: {
    id: "1"
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $('#display_info').html(response);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) allows you send key/value pairs easily in cases like this.
Try and pass the value via FormData as shown below:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', 1);


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update.php',
    data: formData,
...
```